# Tricky ambiguous English

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Aston Villa have released a statement condemning Jack Grealish's
>   decision to ignore "the Government's guidance on staying at home
>   during the Coronavirus crisis. The midfielder **has been fined** by the
>   club with the proceeds **donated** to the University Hospitals Charity in
>   Birmingham

Please, read the paragraph carefully. I'm confused with "the midfielder has been...." part: the fine has **already** been donated or **will** be donated?

[Article Link](https://www.instagram.com/p/B-XZMK_KuqA/?igshid=104lvlrhuj1fw)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't explicitly say that the donation has already been made, or indeed if the fine has been paid. Most fines issued by the police or courts in the UK have a deadline by which they must be paid, and some fines are even allowed to be paid in increments. And under Football Association (FA) rules, "***all fines and charges are payable forthwith and must be paid within 21 days of the date of notification of the decision***". If you know when the decision to fine was made, and you assume that the *notification* of that decision was made the same day (and not delayed by post) then you may be able to determine if it will have been paid yet, but that doesn't make the text any less ambiguous.

> The midfielder has been fined...

This indicates that the fine has been issued, not necessarily that it has been paid.

> ...with the proceeds donated to the University Hospitals Charity in Birmingham.

Note that it does not say "*and* the proceeds donated". By saying "with", it sounds like the donation was a condition of the fine, so it could be a statement of intention rather than a donation that has happened.

Comment: 'Fined by the club' means the club has imposed a financial penalty, effected by reducing the player's next salary payment. The amount was probably paid immediately to the charity

Comment: Thank you, I'm still confused, actually I wanted to be sure that the fine has already been donated or will be donated to the university as fine has been issued

Comment: I think the cited text ***does*** implicitly say that the fine has already been paid, because if payment was still outstanding it would have been *...with the proceeds **to be donated** to the University Hospitals Charity.* That's to say I understand the actual version as written to be "reduced" from *...with the proceeds **having been donated** to...*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I don't think implicit is enough, the OP says he wanted to be sure it was paid. It isn't explicit. Even if an attachment of earnings was made to pay the fine, there would have to be a notice period under UK law. Even if some research in other sources proved it one way or another, that is beyond the scope of this question to determine whether the text is ambiguous or not.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey FA rules say there are 21 days to pay the fine, so I wouldn't assume that it would be taken from earnings, or that it had been paid. Even it was paid by attachment of earnings, most people are paid monthly so they would not have been able to do that for up to a month.

Comment: Hmm. I don't suppose either of us will convince the other, but it seems to me that this "implication" is an aspect of how the English language works in this context (and hence should be significant to people who want to *learn* English). As opposed to possible "real-world" legal procedures, etc., which don't really have anything to do with the language as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I agree that sometimes in English we can speak of things that are certain to be done as if they have already been done. That's why the text doesnt phase me in any way. I also agree it could be implied. But as we've been asked if it has *surely* been paid, I have to say it isn't *sure*.